# R-Shiny - Create radio buttons in tables with columns as selectable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to build in Shiny a table that uses radio buttons. I need the layout to be column specific(Instead of row specific which the example uses). I was following the code example here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/011-radio.html. It appears to be working except I can't get the results to show in the output window.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

c1 = "This is comment 1"
c2 = "This is comment 2"
c3 = "This is comment 3"
c4 = "This is comment 4"
c5 = "This is comment 5"
comments = list(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML("#foo.tr.selected {background-color:red}"))),
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel')
)


  server <- function(input, output) {
    m = matrix(
      as.character(1:5), nrow = 5, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE,
      dimnames = list(comments, LETTERS[1])
    )
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
      m[i, ] = sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        "AValue", m[i, ]
      )
    }
    m
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      m, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
      callback = JS("table.cols().every(function(i, tab, col) {
          var $this = $(this.node());
          $this.attr('id', this.data());
          $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
        });
        Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
        Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      str(sapply(comments, function(i) input[[i]]))
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm assuming that my callback Javascript code has an error in it. I tried some different variations in the code but I can't get the results from the radio button.
Thanks!

Comment: Is it that you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56613036/1100107 ?

Comment: Yes it is. Not sure how I missed this. I think it might be the javascript code was different from the example. Do you know how to add colors to the rows in this example? It's different from the simple examples I was trying to work with: `%>% formatStyle(0, target='row', backgroundColor = styleEqual(3,'red'))'